# Sending custom dimensions with gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics

It's is not at all obvious how to send custom dimensions on pageviews with `gtag.js`. The migration guide does not offer an example: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you found a solution here? Lots of examples for events but none for pageviews.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
gtag('set', {'dimension1': '123'});
gtag('config', 'UA-12345678-1');
```